# Можно ли как-нибудь задать метод функции с помощью переменной?

Tags: python

Что я имею ввиду:
я хочу выполнить код по типу:

```py
schedule.every().saturday.at('12:00').do(func)
```

И вместо `saturday` мне нужно записать `user_week_day`, чтобы получилось так:

```py
schedule.every().user_week_day.at('12:00').do(func)
```

Однако выдает ошибку. Как можно это решить?

Comment: `getattr(schedule.every(), user_week_day).at('12:00').do(func)`.

Answer (score 0):

можно что-то из такого собрать:

```
class A:
    monday = 1
    saturday = 6
    sunday = 7

    def user_week_day(self, day):
        return getattr(self, day)

obj = A()

day = 'monday'
print(obj.user_week_day(day))

day = 'saturday'
print(obj.user_week_day(day))
```

т.е. у вас будет:

```
schedule.every().user_week_day(user_week_day).at('12:00').do(func)
```

Comment: Теперь ошибка "Unresolved attribute reference 'user' for class 'Job' ". Job - это класс в модуле schedule.

Comment: я показал как пример - я же всей вашей структуры не видел, чтобы можно было бы точно сделать решение, приведите полностью свою структуру

Comment: у меня все так как у вас в коде, только функция user_week_day() лежит в другом классе ( var=Var() ). И мой код выглядит так: schedule.every().var.user_week_day(user_week_day).at('12:00').do(func)

Comment: код должен лежать в том классе в котором вы вызываете метод или член класса который хотите задавать через переменную